# PCB relays for switching 700-1000V analog signal

Tags: switches, relay, low-voltage

I'd like to switch the polarity of a differential high voltage line that carries up to a 750V (+/-375V per conductor) analog signal. The easiest way to do this appears to be to use a dual-pole dual-throw (DPDT) relay, with each conductor connected to opposite pins on each pole. My problem is that the parts I've found only support up to around 300V.

I think the constraints of my problem require an electromechanical relay over e.g. a solid state one:

- low contact resistance
- bipolar
- linear

I don't care about driving current (the load is a capacitor) or switching speed. The control voltage can be anything below 20V or so.

Does anyone know of a suitable electromechanical relay that could switch this voltage, or another way to solve this problem?

Comment: The worst load possible is a capacitor so details please and can resistors be used to lower inrush currents?

Comment: @Andyaka: capacitance is low - 100pF or so - and resistors could be used as long as the low-pass filter created is not limiting the signal below say 100kHz, so R <= 10k or so would probably be alright, but even lower is best to avoid slew rate problems and too large a voltage drop.

Comment: I used somewhat expensive reed relays rated for 10 kV at 300 mA. Maybe $15 USD from Allied/Digi-Key/Mouser. The 24 VDC coil is expensive. About $25 USD. I have not seen a contactor rated more than 750 VAC at 350 A.

Comment: @Sparky256: that's what I've decided to go for. I need four of them to do what I want, and need also a delay circuit to break before make. I'll post an update when I've built it.

Answer (score 2):

Do a parametric search at a distributor. The Omron [G7L-2A-X-L DC12](http://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g7l_x.pdf) wired with contacts in series appears to meet your requirements **if** you can limit the current. It's relatively economical (less than $100). You would, however, require four of them.

A high voltage and a capacitor with mechanical contacts closing are essentially a CD welder and **will** cause the contacts to stick if you don't limit the current, preferably with a non-inductive resistor rated for the full voltage and for the power impulse it will experience.

---

You could also try to make an H-bridge with PV optoisolators and 4x high-voltage MOSFETs. You would have to avoid excessive shoot-through current or your MOSFETs will be damaged (as in potentially blown to small bits).

---

A third possibility would be to use a well-designed relay that meets high coil-contact breakdown voltage specs (eg. for AC compressor use such as G7J Omron) and characterize it yourself. There is no guarantee this would be reliable or safe but I suspect it would work. A caution- there is no guarantee that high AC voltage (eg. 4kV) surge ratings translate reliably into continuous DC voltage specifications. That particular one is rated for 10kV peak coil-contact surge and 4kV/2kVAC for 1 minute. All safety concerns need to be fully addressed by the designer (that's you).

Answer (score 1):

You can look for high voltage relays which are gas or vacuum filled.  Gigavac is one supplier.  You  do need to be aware of current when switching a capacitive load, because you will have a surge current when charging the capacitor.

Comment: Thanks. The Gigavac parts seem like overkill, being rated for 10s of kV, and made of ceramic. I expect they're very expensive. This is supposed to be a hack for an existing piece of electronics so I'd rather not spend too much if I can avoid it. It seems like I'm in a niche between what PCB relays provide and what these gas/vacuum tubes provide... As for capacitive load, it's a really small capacitor - a few hundred pF, perhaps.

Comment: Last time I bought a Gigavac relay they were about $250 for a SPST at 5 KV.  If you are only switching a few hundred pf, you could try reed relays (or reed switches).  You can get them in high voltage for a few bucks but only single pole.  If you use four of them, you will have to use some logic to make sure they break before make.